# How to find missing date range in a month [NODE JS]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, date, momentjs

For example, user chooses a month range from 01/2020 to 01/2020 to filter uploaded reports and he has a report with date range from 06/01/2020 to 13/01/2020. This does not qualify the requirements, since it has missing date ranges to complete the month (from 01/01/2020 to 06/01/2020 and from 13/01/2020 to 31/01/2020). So, I need to find that missing date ranges in that month and ask user to upload reports for that period of time. I have already tried to get array of missing dates by finding the difference of array of all days in the given month (01/2020 - 01/2020) (filterDateArray) and array of days that report has (06/01/2020 - 13/01/2020) (existingDateArray):

```
filterDateArray.filter(x => !existingDateArray.includes(x))
```

This returns array of all missing dates in month

```
[
  '01/01/2020', '02/01/2020',
  '03/01/2020', '04/01/2020',
  '05/01/2020', '14/01/2020',
  '15/01/2020', '16/01/2020',
  '17/01/2020', '18/01/2020',
  '19/01/2020', '20/01/2020',
  '21/01/2020', '22/01/2020',
  '23/01/2020', '24/01/2020',
  '25/01/2020', '26/01/2020',
  '27/01/2020', '28/01/2020',
  '29/01/2020', '30/01/2020',
  '31/01/2020'
]
```

The problem is that, I can not take date ranges for missing reports from this array. Expected result should be date range from 01/01/2020 to 06/01/2020 and from 13/01/2020 to 31/01/2020. It means that user should upload at least two more reports to complete the month

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the missing ranges are:

- 01/01/2020 - 05/01/2020
- 14/01/2020 - 31/01/2020.

You can create a function to create ranges from an array of dates that starts and ends the first range on the first date. It then and checks if each subsequent date is the next day. When it isn't, then the previous date is the last day of the range and the current date is the first day of the next range, and so on. When it reaches the end of the array, it closes the current range if there is.

E.g. with modified the data to include single day ranges:

```js
// parse d/m/y to Date
function datesToRanges(dates) {
  let parse = s => {
    let [d, m, y] = s.split(/\D/);
    return new Date(y, m-1, d);
  }
  // Add 1 day to a date, return the date
  let add = d => {
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    return d;
  }
  // Pad single digit numbers with leading zero
  let z = n => (n<10?'0':'') + n;
  // Format Date as d/m/y
  let format = d => `${z(d.getDate())}/${z(d.getMonth()+1)}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
  
  // Initialise variables
  let startRange, endRange, endPlusOne, ranges = [];
      
  // Loop over dates
  for (let i=0, iLen=dates.length; i < iLen; i++) {
  
    // Initialise start and end range if not set
    if (!startRange) {
      startRange = dates[i];
      endRange = startRange;
      i++;
    }
  
    // Get a string for endRange + 1 day
    endPlusOne = format(add(parse(endRange)));
    
    // If current == next date and there are more dates
    // to come, update endRange
    if (endPlusOne == dates[i] && dates[i+1]) {
      endRange = endPlusOne;
      
    // Otherwise, at end of current range
    // Write range to result, update start and end
    // If at end of array, write last range
    } else {
      ranges.push(startRange + ' - ' + endRange);
      startRange = dates[i];
      endRange = startRange;

      // Check if at end of dates array and have started a range
      if (!dates[i+1] && startRange) {
        ranges.push(startRange + ' - ' + endRange);
      }
    }
  }
  return ranges;
}

// data
let dates = ['01/01/2020',                           // Single date at start
             '03/01/2020','04/01/2020','05/01/2020', // 3 day range
             '14/01/2020','15/01/2020','16/01/2020', // 7 day range
             '17/01/2020','18/01/2020','19/01/2020',
             '20/01/2020',
             '22/01/2020',                           // Single date range
             '24/01/2020','25/01/2020','26/01/2020', // 6 day range
             '27/01/2020','28/01/2020','29/01/2020',
             '31/01/2020'];                          // Single date at end

console.log(datesToRanges(dates).join('\n'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your annswer! However, I need date range from 01/01/2020 to 06/01/2020 and from 13/01/2020 to 31/01/2020 (06/01/2020 and 13/01/2020 should be included)., when date range is chosen by user from 01/2020 to 01/2020 (January). If user increases the date range, ex. from 01/2020 to 02/2020 (January - February), since there is no report for February, there should be 3 missing date ranges: 01/01/2020 - 06/01/2020, 13/01/2020 - 31/01/2020, 01/02/2020 - 29/02/2020